# Material table next page not working when i click it

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Can someone help me please my next page when I click does not work?

Here's my sandbox link any help will be much appreciated been stuck on this problem all day yesterday.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-bohr-k8hqj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the the issue is with @material-ui/core latest library version. Upgrade to v14.12.1 causing prop type errors in the material-table library. There is a [bug #2935](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2935) reported recently which is still open.

Meanwhile the simple workaround here would be downgrading the @material-ui/core version to [v4.12.0](https://material-ui.com/versions/) or below. try removing the latest version and downgrade to the following version.

```
yarn add @material-ui/core@4.12.0
```